# Can mount slot items like Impenetrable Barding be used with figurines of power?

Tags: dnd-4e, mount

I imagine a mount slot item as something the mount carries/wears.

When you use the Figurines such as the ebony fly they tend to be of use in just one or two combats--with a standard action they grow to full size and you can choose to already be mounted, but what happens to the mount slot item?  Is it automatically "mounted" or do you have to get off and take a few turns placing it on your mount in the middle of combat?

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any rules about this, I am quite sure there is none. I would say if it was wearing the saddle when you dismissed it, it should wear it when it appears. It is certainly not overpowered, as long as you treat the saddle dismissed as well.

Comment: As long as you don't assume to have the object with you while the mount is absent.

Comment: Good point, added to the answer.